Website rejecting Android Webview application
Can someone help me with a problem please.
I wrote an app a while ago which logs onto my company website to download scheduling information so I have it available offline. It uses Android's WebView and javascript and has been working for ages but in the last few days is has stopped working. I suspect that the company has detected that it is not a true browser and blocks the requests. The reason for this is that I have written a very simple test program, all it does is load the url and I'm getting the same problem.
For testing this app I am using the Android Studio Code emulator.
I have tried the url in chrome on the emulator and it works fine however when calling the URL in the app it gets rejected.
The code is very simple so I am sure that its nothing I've done.
       webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.loadUrl(MainActivity.weburl);

I've fetch the User Agent data and that is as follows.
From the App
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; sdk_gphone_x86 Build/RSR1.210722.013.A2; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile Safari/537.36

and from chrome I get
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; sdk_gphone_x86) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile Safari/537.36

I know they're different but I have tried setting the User Agent to the one from Chrome as it still didn't work. Not even sure if its User Agent that is being used so is there another parameter that the website could be using?
Many thanks in advance
***** IMAGE FOR RESPONSE ADDED *****


There's no log and no HTTP status code, therefore this is pure guessing ...

There is no log. The website I'm trying to access just sends some html back saying invalid Request.

What is your company's stance towards accessing their website in this manner? Maybe they have legitimate reasons to block this. Have you verified you are not violating the rules of conduct or similar regulations?

I have valid access to the website, which works fine in Chrome. I just was Webview to behave and be seen just like Chrome. The data that I will be able to access is fully available for me to view in Chrome, or any other browser for that matter.

There's no such thing as an "invalid request", there only HTTP 400 Bad Request which means that something's wrong with the request, which most often are bad or missing HTTP headers. Asking the IT department what changed might be rather leading than letting us guess what the cause may be. Just press F12 in Chrome and inspect the request, then emulate it ...

I am getting HTTP Code 400 but what I don't know and am struggling with is if its the general HTTP server that is rejecting my request or whether the web server code is spotting something in my request and manually rejecting the request. I've posted an image showing the response data in the original question.
